# Connecting tables in database with SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect two tables in my database.
I have table user and table authorities.

User table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Authorities table:

```
CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `authorities_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorities` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`authorities_id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES user(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Tables were created like this. When creating authorities table I got error that table can't be created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `Authorities` you reference `user`, but your table is called `student`

Comment: @HoneyBadger sorry I edited it. My mistake. Now is same as in database.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table 'app.authorities' (errno: 150) @HoneyBadger

Comment: The syntax looks okay to me, and also works when using http://rextester.com/. Is it possible the table already exists, and hasn't been dropped?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code either without "CONSTRAINT "

```
CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `authorities_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorities` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`authorities_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES user(`id`)
   ON DELETE CASCADE 

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

or

give name to CONSTRAINT

```
CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `authorities_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorities` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`authorities_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_authorities_user` FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES user(`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

one more issue in INNODB you can not use  "ON DELETE SET DEFAULT" you have to use "ON DELETE CASCADE" or "ON DELETE SET NULL"

Comment: there is one more issue with innodb engine can not use  DELETE SET DEFAULT.